# Flutter Error: File 'com.android.builder.files.ZipCentralDirectory@7869c730' was deleted, but previous version not found in cache

Tags: flutter, dart

I was coding my flutter app and from nowhere an error popped up and i searched everywhere to fix it but I cant. There are no errors in the files

this is the error shown in debug console

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > File 'com.android.builder.files.ZipCentralDirectory@7869c730' was deleted, but previous version not found in cache

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > File 'com.android.builder.files.ZipCentralDirectory@4d38c6ab' was deleted, but previous version not found in cache

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 13s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

**Please help me out**....

Answer (score 5):

flutter clean command resolves this issue

Comment: flutter clean command doent resolves this issue

Comment: did you try flutter pub get after the clean command?

Answer (score 4):

just running

> ./gradlew clean

worked for me (react-native)

Answer (score 1):

This is how i get the solution

Flutter clean
try to build again

if it fails
delete the 'build' folder from root directory manually

run flutter pub get
then try to build again

That steps helped me to resolve my issue

Answer (score 0):

1. Restart the pc
2. `flutter clean`
3. `flutter pug get`